# What's the name of this square matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I have a square matrix described by $a_{ij} = \alpha^{|i-j|}$ (typically $0 < \alpha < 1$). E.g. for a $4 \times 4$ matrix with $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8}  \\
\frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I call it a "smoothing matrix" because if we multiply a vector by it, we get something like an unnormalized moving average with weights decreasing exponentially with distance. Does it have an established name?

Comment: This is also a symmetric matrix. $A^T= A$ where $A^T$ is transpose of the matrix.

Comment: Yep, also a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), but does the idea of values decreasing exponentially (with distance from the diagonal) have a more specific name?

Comment: It's a Kac–Murdock–Szegö matrix.

Comment: https://nhigham.com/2021/07/06/what-is-the-kac-murdock-szego-matrix/